# How to debug the error "AAPT2 error: check logs for details"?

Tags: android, aapt2

Here is my log file. Please kindly go through it:

```
/**********************************************************************

2018-06-29 18:34:27,811 [thread 101]   INFO -                    #InstantRun - Local build timestamp is empty! 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,330 [thread 101]   INFO - ools.idea.fd.InstantRunBuilder - BuildCause: MISMATCHING_TIMESTAMPS, BuildMode: FULL 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,331 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,331 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: BUILD_EXECUTOR_CREATED 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,344 [ thread 90]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,358 [ thread 90]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.local.repo contents "allprojects {\n  buildscript {\n    repositories {\n      maven { url 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\gradle\\\\m2repository'}\n    }\n  }\n  repositories {\n      maven { url 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\gradle\\\\m2repository'}\n  }\n}\n" 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,359 [ thread 90]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=22, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=hdpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug, -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app, -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV,FULL_APK, -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK, --no-build-cache, --init-script, C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.local.repo1354.gradle] 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,406 [ thread 90]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --configure-on-demand -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.api=22 -Pandroid.injected.build.density=hdpi -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.name=debug -Pandroid.injected.restrict.variant.project=:app -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV,FULL_APK -Pandroid.injected.coldswap.mode=MULTIAPK --no-build-cache --init-script C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.local.repo1354.gradle 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,465 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: BUILD_STARTED 

2018-06-29 18:34:28,466 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'F:\Android\Gallary_Frame' Gallary_Frame 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,117 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: BUILD_FINISHED 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,118 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'F:\Android\Gallary_Frame' Gallary_Frame 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,118 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 3s 771ms 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,129 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,220 [thread 101]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models. 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,225 [thread 101]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = false 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,326 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,438 [cessToken]]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 

2018-06-29 18:34:32,673 [thread 101]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 107ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 

2018-06-29 18:34:34,143 [thread 101]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1470ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 0/1 sluggish, 1/1 very slow 

2018-06-29 18:34:34,143 [thread 101]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 14 files to update 

2018-06-29 18:34:34,245 [thread 101]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 102ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
**********************************************************************/
```

I really have no idea what's going on. In code there is no `error` but after trying 5-6 time it build and install successfully.

But on every small changes I have to try again 5-6 times or more to build project.

Application is working perfect but this Android Studio taking lot of my time on small changes.

I already tried all possible solution posted on internet.

Comment: What does your application consist of? Only java code or is there more to it (like C++ code)? Do you have many resource files or just a few?

Comment: Well I am new in Android firm.. but on fail I found this Line "AAPT2 error: check logs for details"

Comment: too small application.. only gallery view application..

Comment: Compare logs for successful and failing builds. Perhaps post both kinds. Without both kinds of logs this question isn't actionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable instant run option from your settings. `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run`. Then uncheck the box to disable it. Now `Clean Build` and run again. It should work.

Comment: Well, This help me after Re-Install Android Studio. Thanks For Help.

Comment: I also Tried this solution before but this help me after only re-installing Android Studio today.. I also Change root Dir. and set on full access.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helps.